# cocos2d 3.4 with Spine - Reduce draw calls / batching draw calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, swift, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using Spine together with cocos2d-objc 3.4 and I'd like to get my draw calls down to 1 ideally when only using one sprite sheet.

At the moment a simple animation takes 10 draw calls and adding it one more time results in double the draw calls.

1) How do you make Spine and cocos2d 3.4 only have one single draw call when using only one sprite sheet?

2) How can you batch draw multiple spine animations from the same sheet?

Comment: One seems unlikely ... you could read this great article by Scott Lembcke on render ordering and batching. You will see that many conditions can affect the batching process. A change in Z, a change in blending mode, a CCLabelTTF, etc ...  https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-objc/wiki/Cocos2D-Render-Order-and-Batching

Comment: I agree that one might be ambitious, but I'm talking about a very simple animation with spine. Literally just one character. I'm trying to find out the best and fastest way to render with spine.